# HERE API not found import 'package:here_sdk/consent.dart' in the HERE_SDK_REF_APP project

Tags: flutter, here-api

Importing package:here_sdk/consent.dart not found

I am trying to run HERE_SDK_REF_APP. I already installed here sdk in the PLUGIN folder and I can run other examples, but with `HERE_SDK_REF_APP` I get this error message.

```
lib/landing_screen.dart:25:8: Error: Error when reading 'plugins/here_sdk/lib/consent.dart': O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.
```

I searched for this file, `consent.dart`  in the package, project and in the plugin but this file does not exist.

What can be wrong ?

Thank´s a lot
Everson Badaro

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong HERE SDK edition. Have you double-checked that you use the correct version and edition as stated here: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-ref-app-flutter ?